# How to add the product filter in the sidebar?

Tags: layout, theme, filter

I just want to add the default filter in my sidebar. When looking at the official [Magento demo](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/electronics/cellphones), you can see this on the left sidebar (Shopping Options.) I assume this is available out of the box to enable since the Magento demo shouldn't be using community modules (I think.)

Comment: Can you please eloborate your question and explain in detail what exactly you want.

Comment: I don't understand how I can elaborate...I want the sidebar filter as in the link? How do I enable the sidebar filter?

Comment: There is no sidebar filter in the link. Do you want the default product filter as in this link `http://demo.magentocommerce.com/apparel`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Goto Admin panel

```
Catalog->Manage Categories
```

Click on your category then goto `Display Setting` Tab

> Set **Is Anchor** -> yes

now you'll set filter options in left side bar.

If you not get the filter,

in admin panel category edit check `Custom design` Tab

set page layout as `2columns-left.phmtl or 3columns.phtml`

or check your catalog.xml file in that make sure the category view page template is `2columns-left.phmtl or 3columns.phtml`

Comment: I have followed the above step and filter is showing on the product page but right now its only showing the price filter. One more thing once I have applied the filter and clear the filter but it still showing the `There are no products matching the selection.`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is probably [layered navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work) that you refer to. You can enable this on a per category basis by setting `Is Anchor` to `Yes` on the `Display Settings` tab as explained [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/anchor-categories).