# Show price filter in sidebar of product page

Tags: price, filter

I want to show price filter in sidebar of product page. I set price attribute to show in front end but nothing happen!!!

How can I show it in product page?

Comment: have you set the use layered navigation filter option to yes?

Comment: @saravanavelu: in price attribute I set layered navigation to filtering with result. Do you mean this?

Comment: yes.the same...how you filter the price in product page?

Comment: @saravanavelu: I just set this is back end.

Comment: does it show if you switch to base theme? maybe your theme excluded it

Comment: @Claudiu: The theme supported it, It was in demo of theme. I thinks I should set something else that I miss it.

Comment: I found my answer here: [how-to-add-the-product-filter-in-the-sidebar](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15598/how-to-add-the-product-filter-in-the-sidebar)